# Update view schema

Tags: oracle, view

Hi I would like to be able to update a view to point to a table in a different schema as in example below, change SCHEMA1 to SCHEMA2. No other change to the SQL.

Can anyone suggest an efficient  way to achieve this, ideally a string replacement.

I can do CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW and provide the list of fields. This doesn't seem a good option as I have about 40 views re repoint.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW CUST.CustOrdersView as 
 SELECT field1, field2 etc.. from 
 SCHEMA1.CUSTOMER ;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "table schema of a view" ? Do we really have such a thing in Oracle ? And what is "list of fields should remain as is" ? Please don't make up your own terms to describe your problem. By doing so, you confuse others. Tell us what exactly is your problem with an example.

Comment: I have edited my post and provided an example. Does this make it clear what I am trying to do ?

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL; get the current view DDL, replace the schema name, execute it. But you'll need to update the DDL held in your source code repository anyway... right...?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simply that you have hardcoded the schema name in the views' queries. Instead of that you could have created a synonym:

```
create synonym CUSTOMER for SCHEMA1.CUSTOMER;
```

Then in your view you would have simply referenced CUSTOMER.

To repoint the view to another schema you would have to change the synonyms:

```
create or replace synonym CUSTOMER for SCHEMA2.CUSTOMER;
```

That's still work but it's much easier to generate those statements from the data dictionary views than it is to change all the view queries.

(If there is a namespace clash - that is, if schema which owns the views already has an object called CUSTOMER - you would need to use a different name for the schema.)

---

You may not regard this as a helpful answer, because it doesn't really solve your current problem, but it may help you avoid a similar situation in the future.

Comment: Thanks. This is all useful. I have ended up using dynamic sql in a stored procedure to do this as Alex pointed out.